# Disable Map Zoom on Mouse Scroll when Info Window is open , But Allow scrolling of Content in info window

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am Using Google Map, I show information on Info window when marker is clicked. The information has a very long description thus User has to scroll to read full description. 
However when Info window is open and my mouse pointer is on the description and I scroll, the content is not scrolled but map is zoomed out. 
I tried disabled the zoom using below :

```
#map-canvas{pointer-events: auto;}

#map-canvas.opened{
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

But this stops me to scroll my info window content and I am not able to move the map.

I just want to stop zoom out and zoom in on mouse scroll when info window is open and allow scrolling of content on using Mouse Scroller. 
[image]

Any way out ?

Answer (score 1):

Below line will fix your problem.

map.setOptions({scrollwheel:false});

Please use in google.maps.event.addListener click event.